# Wireframe not showing in edit mode

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

[image: Wireframe in object mode]

[image: No wireframe in edit mode]

[image]

[image]

Hello, I am currently starting Blender by watching Blender Guru youtube videos. I was wondering how to solve this

Comment: AFAIK this is "normal". Not applied subdiv modifiers won't be shown in edit mode.

Comment: As Chris says, it may have been possible with the version BG used but it doesn't seem possible in the latest versions in Edit mode, or I'm missing the option...

Comment: I just downloaded the previous 3.0.0 version, and it's working. Thanks for the reply